# Adding an image in an html code

Tags: html, css

I am new to html. I have been trying to insert an image

> http://placehold.it/1000x500

in the following html code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Framework Test page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="grid">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">2 Columns</div>
            <div class="col-10">ss</div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">3 Columns</div>
            <div class="col-9">9 Columns</div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">4 Columns</div>
            <div class="col-4">4 Columns</div>
            <div class="col-4">4 Columns</div>
        </div>


    </div>
    <div class="image"><img="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Yoo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

with the css file

```
*{
    border: 1px solid red !important;
}
*{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.grid{
    margin: 0 auto;
     max-width: 1200px;
    width: 100%;
}
.row{
    width:100%;

    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
*{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.text{
    margin:20px;
}
.col-1{
    width:8.33%;
}
.col-2{
    width:16.66%;
}
.col-3{
    width:25%;
}
.col-4{
    width:33.33%;
}
.col-5{
    width:41.66%;
}
.col-6{
    width:50%;
}
.col-7{
    width:58.33%;
}
.col-8{
    width:66.66%;
}
.col-9{
    width:75%;
}
.col-10{
    width:83.33%;
}
.col-11{
    width:91.66%;
}
.col-12{
    width:100%;
}
```

But I am not getting the image when I am opening the file in my browser. But the same image is getting displayed for another html code. Please tell the problem and the solution.

Comment: An IMG tag is self closing, meaning you need to end the tag with "/>" and not ">". Also you need to start with <img src="URL HERE", not simply img="URL"

Answer (score 3):

You have an error with

```
<img="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Yoo">
```

You have forgottton to add the `src=` part.

Instead, use:

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Yoo">
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the [`src`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Attributes). 
The correct syntax for an image is:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Yoo" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
<div class="image"><img="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Yoo"></div>
```

To

```
<div class="image"><img src ="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Yoo"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use This

```
<div class="image"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Yoo" border="0" /></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="image"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Yoo"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code:-

```
<div class="image"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Yoo" border="0" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the image code with this

```
<div class="image"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Yoo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your html..

Replace this line:

```
<div class="image"><img="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Yoo"></div>
```

With this line

```
<div class="image"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Yoo"></div>
```

Check out the demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/4h5e0ha5/

Answer (score 0):

The Syntax in wrong you should add src(source) attribute to link any image from drive or from web site 
Just add

```
    <img src="path" />
```

and dont forget to close the tag :P

Comment: It doesn't matter, if the tag is selfclosing or not in HTML5